# Filter nested object in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to filter an nested array of objects but it's not working as expected....

Here is my json:

```js
[
    {
      "seasson_number": "1",
      "episodes": [
        {
          "number": 1,
          "video_url": "http://test.com",
          "name": "Testing"
        },
        {
          "number": 2,
          "video_url": "http://test.com",
          "name": "Testing"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "seasson_number": "2",
      "episodes": [
        {
          "number": 1,
          "video_url": "http://test.com",
          "name": "Testing"
        },
        {
          "number": 2,
          "video_url": "http://test.com",
          "name": "Testing"
        }
      ]      
    }
]
```

And this is my function to filter by the seasson_number and get the episode name:

```
const episodios = this.state.seassons
        .filter(seasson => {
            return seasson.seasson_number === "2"; // sample number
        })
        .map(seasson => {
            seasson.episodes.map(episode =>{
                return (
                    <h2>{episode.name}</h2>
                )
            })                
        });
```

Comment: so your issue is that there's no output?

Comment: What does your component look like for displaying these episodes?

Comment: @fodma1 yeah, it returns and single empty <h2></h2>

Comment: === comparisons check also if the types of variables are the same. Are you sure seasson.seasson_number is a string?

Comment: @ZachStoltz I'm just trying to display some <h2> inside and <div>

Comment: @NatanielRichardt look at the below answer.  You just forgot to return the episodes in the "map" function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first map function, you should add a return statement:

```
map(seasson => {
        return seasson.episodes.map(episode =>{
            return (
                <h2>{episode.name}</h2>
            )
        })                
    });
```

Comment: The first part is not correct because if the seasson_number in the object is "2" than "2" === "2" will return true.

Comment: season  number is a string, the issue is the first return

Comment: I have just thought it's a number because of the variable name "seasson_number". Don't blame me for this :

Comment: nobody is blaming you but it is plainly in the original post. The focus of your answer should be the missing return statement and I'd suggest editing it so this answer is clear for any future readers

Comment: I approved the modification of Zach Stoltz. Hope this will help other users :)